# Practices based on the Zohar

Tags: mysticism-kabbalah, zohar, arizal

Which jewish practices (or stringencies) are based solely on the Zohar and later texts based on the Zohar such as the writings of Rabbi Yitzhak Luria (Arizal)?

Some of my own findings:

- Not walking 4 amos before washing netilas yadayim when you wake up in the morning. (Zohar)
- [Upsheren](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upsherin) not cutting a boys hair until he is 3 years old (Arizal)
- Avoiding eating pas palter (kosher bread sold by a non-jew) (Arizal)
- [Nusach Sfard](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nusach_Sefard) (Arizal)
- Ksav Arizal (Arizal) [image: Arizal script has some small changes]
- Not learning the written Torah at night (Zohar)

Answer (score 4):

The prayer בריך שמיה is taken from the [Zohar](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%96%D7%94%D7%A8_%D7%97%D7%9C%D7%A7_%D7%91_%D7%A8%D7%95_%D7%90), as is seemingly the practice to say this prayer by the opening of the Aron Kodesh.

Comment: [This is perhaps not the case.](https://jstudies.huji.ac.il/sites/default/files/jstudies/files/tarbiz_-_8601_-_archive_-_20.12.2018_-_5_-_pp._147-198_-_bar-asher.pdf)

Answer (score 3):

- Sitting while putting on the tefillin shel yad. (Zohar)
- Throwing the chalitzah shoe. (Zohar)
- Not to wash netilas yadayim of the morning onto the ground but only in a vessel. (Zohar)
- Putting on tzitzis and tefillin at home before entering shul (Zohar veschanan)
- Putting talis over ones head during shmoneh esrei so not to be distracted (Zohar, Va'eschanan)

Answer (score 1):

I believe starting Kiddush with "וַיְהִי עֶרֶב וַיְהִי בֹקֶר יוֹם הַשִּׁשִּׁי" is minhag brought down by the Zohar or the Arizal. Actual halakha and mesorah is to begin Kiddush with "וַיְכַל אֱלֹהִים בַּיוֹם הַשְּׁבִיעי"

Comment: Can you source either of these statements?